# Он не знал, где дети — может, в кино, а может, дома. Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: придаточное-предложение

Он не знал, где дети — может, в кино, а может, дома.

Что собой представляет конструкция после тире и относится ли она к придаточной части или ко всему предложению? Тогда соответственно не ставить перед тире запятую или нет?

И можно ли заменить тире двоеточием?

Он не знал, где дети: может, в кино, а может, дома.

Answer (score 1):

Она относится ко всему предложению, в этом легко убедиться перевернув часть до тире:

> Где дети, он не знал — может, в кино, а может, дома.

Так что запятая перед тире в исходном варианте нужна.

Что касается двоеточия, то:

> Двоеточие в бессоюзном сложном предложении, распадающемся на две части, ставится:
>
> 1. если вторая часть (одно или несколько предложений) разъясняет, раскрывает содержание первой части (между обеими частями можно вставить слова «а именно»)

[(Розенталь, § 117)](http://rosental-book.ru/punct_xxx.html#sect117)

Я считаю, здесь можно применить это правило, хотя с тире, мне кажется, лучше.

Answer (score 1):

**(1)  Он не знал, где дети — может, в кино, а может, дома. (2) Он не знал, где дети: может, в кино, а может, дома.**

Однородный ряд является **присоединительной конструкцией с собственными знаками препинания.** Основная форма — обособление **тире**. Также Розенталь допускает использование **двоеточия**.

**Запятая** в этом случае не подходит.